# With Formio.JS, possible to group components?

Tags: javascript, formio

I know we can create custom components, but I am curious if there is a way to group a few together into either a `Container` or a `Panel`?

For instance, why make everyone create the same 4 fields in a pleasing layout over and over to create a panel for getting a user's Address? Seems like it would be nice to be able to define some buttons on the left that says "Address Form Block", or "Contact Info Block" which then inserts everything in a group.

I am still pretty new to using Formio.JS, so I don't know if this is possible, but I would hope I am not the first to want something like this.

Example form:
[image]

Sample Code:

```
Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {
    "display": "form",
    
    "components": [
       {
            "title": "Demographics",
            "collapsible": false,
            "key": "demographics",
            "type": "panel",
            "label": "Panel",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "components": [
        {
            "label": "Columns",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "label": "Last Name",
                            "tableView": true,
                            "key": "lastName1",
                            "type": "textfield",
                            "input": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 5,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 5
                },
                {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "label": "First Name",
                            "tableView": true,
                            "key": "lastName",
                            "type": "textfield",
                            "input": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 5,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 5
                },
                {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "label": "Middle Initial",
                            "tableView": true,
                            "key": "middleInitial",
                            "type": "textfield",
                            "input": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": "md",
                    "width": 2,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "currentWidth": 2
                }
            ],
            "key": "columns",
            "type": "columns",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
        },
        {
            "label": "Birthdate",
            "hideInputLabels": false,
            "inputsLabelPosition": "top",
            "useLocaleSettings": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "fields": {
                "day": {
                    "hide": false
                },
                "month": {
                    "hide": false
                },
                "year": {
                    "hide": false
                }
            },
            "key": "birthdate",
            "type": "day",
            "input": true,
            "defaultValue": "00/00/0000"
        },
        {
            "label": "Phone Number",
            "tableView": true,
            "key": "phoneNumber",
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true
        }]},
        {
            "title": "Address",
            "collapsible": false,
            "key": "address",
            "type": "panel",
            "label": "Panel",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "components": [
                {
                    "label": "Street Address",
                    "tableView": true,
                    "key": "streetAddress",
                    "type": "textfield",
                    "input": true
                },
                {
                    "label": "Columns",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "components": [
                                {
                                    "label": "City",
                                    "tableView": true,
                                    "key": "city",
                                    "type": "textfield",
                                    "input": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": 6,
                            "offset": 0,
                            "push": 0,
                            "pull": 0,
                            "size": "md",
                            "currentWidth": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "components": [
                                {
                                    "label": "State",
                                    "tableView": true,
                                    "key": "state",
                                    "type": "textfield",
                                    "input": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "width": 3,
                            "offset": 0,
                            "push": 0,
                            "pull": 0,
                            "size": "md",
                            "currentWidth": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "components": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Zipcode",
                                    "tableView": true,
                                    "key": "zipcode",
                                    "type": "textfield",
                                    "input": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "size": "md",
                            "width": 3,
                            "offset": 0,
                            "push": 0,
                            "pull": 0,
                            "currentWidth": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "key": "columns1",
                    "type": "columns",
                    "input": false,
                    "tableView": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Signature",
            "tableView": false,
            "key": "signature",
            "type": "signature",
            "input": true
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "label": "Submit",
            "key": "submit",
            "disableOnInvalid": true,
            "input": true,
            "tableView": false
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom component option like.

```
const AddressTool = {
    "title": "Address",
    "collapsible": false,
    "key": "address",
    "type": "panel",
    "label": "Panel",
    "input": false,
    "tableView": false,
    "components": [{
            "label": "Street Address",
            "tableView": true,
            "key": "streetAddress",
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true
        },
        {
            "label": "Columns",
            "columns": [{
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "City",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "city",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "width": 6,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 6
                },
                {
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "State",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "state",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "width": 3,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 3
                },
                {
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "Zipcode",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "zipcode",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "size": "md",
                    "width": 3,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "currentWidth": 3
                }
            ],
            "key": "columns1",
            "type": "columns",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
        }
    ]
};
const DemographicsTool = {
    "title": "Demographics",
    "collapsible": false,
    "key": "demographics",
    "type": "panel",
    "label": "Panel",
    "input": false,
    "tableView": false,
    "components": [{
            "label": "Columns",
            "columns": [{
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "lastName1",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "width": 5,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 5
                },
                {
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "lastName",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "width": 5,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "size": "md",
                    "currentWidth": 5
                },
                {
                    "components": [{
                        "label": "Middle Initial",
                        "tableView": true,
                        "key": "middleInitial",
                        "type": "textfield",
                        "input": true
                    }],
                    "size": "md",
                    "width": 2,
                    "offset": 0,
                    "push": 0,
                    "pull": 0,
                    "currentWidth": 2
                }
            ],
            "key": "columns",
            "type": "columns",
            "input": false,
            "tableView": false
        },
        {
            "label": "Birthdate",
            "hideInputLabels": false,
            "inputsLabelPosition": "top",
            "useLocaleSettings": false,
            "tableView": false,
            "fields": {
                "day": {
                    "hide": false
                },
                "month": {
                    "hide": false
                },
                "year": {
                    "hide": false
                }
            },
            "key": "birthdate",
            "type": "day",
            "input": true,
            "defaultValue": "00/00/0000"
        },
        {
            "label": "Phone Number",
            "tableView": true,
            "key": "phoneNumber",
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true
        }
    ]
};

let formioOptions = {
    noDefaultSubmitButton: false,
    builder: {
        basic: false,
        advanced: false,
        data: false,
        premium: false,
        layout: false,
        custom: {
            title: 'Custom Component Set',
            weight: 10,
            components: {
                Demographics: {
                    title: 'Demographics',
                    key: 'demographics',
                    icon: 'terminal',
                    schema: DemographicsTool
                },
                Address: {
                    title: 'Address',
                    key: 'address',
                    icon: 'terminal',
                    schema: AddressTool
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and then call the builder

```
Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {
    "components": [{
        "title": "Test1",
        "input": false,
        "key": "panel1",
        "tableView": false,
        "label": "Test 1",
        "type": "panel",
        "collapsed": false,
        "collapsible": true,
        "components": [AddressTool, DemographicsTool]
    }]
}, formioOptions);
```