# formio, instance multiple base component in custom component

Tags: javascript, formio

I'm trying to create a custom component having a combination of 3 base Select formio components (similar to the "day" component), but using the https://help.form.io/developers/custom-components guide.

I could create manually the dropdowns using the "select" template render, but in doing so i'm missing all the formio Select logics (expecially the multiselect https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/select.html), and I don't understand how can I just instance a formio Select in my custom component.

I saw a similar question in [With Formio.JS, possible to group components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808700/with-formio-js-possible-to-group-components) but there it doesn't use the custom component logics.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Mewster, can you provide a minimally reproducible example (a JSFiddle, for example) of the custom component you're trying to create and what problems you're running into?

Comment: I don't have a working example, but this https://jsfiddle.net/pne0fxrc/ is a dumbed down example of what I'm trying to do, copied from formio's "day" component.  While this would render basic html options, I wanted to instance the "formio" select component

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the 'editForm' of the Select Component like this.

try logging the following statement

```
Components.components.select.editForm();
```

'Components' is imported from the library.

```
import { Components } from 'angular-formio';
```

this would log a lengthy JSON for the select component. The same one is used when using the select component in Form IO. you can make changes to this, to add your fields or add/remove tabs.